# Issue with preg_match Search String

Tags: php

I have the following code :

```
$base_url = "http://www.WWWW.com/npcs/";
$url = $base_url.$npc;
$page = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match('/class="db-left">Leveld+/', $page, $level_match);
```

This is the original search which I need to find , tryed all sorts of variations of the search field and can't seem to find one that works , all of them make $level_match null.
After the Level there should be some numbers like with a space before "15 22".
I need the script to return only those numbers. Can't use only Level as the search since it will get more then 1 result.

Comment: `$` in your regex means that the `$page` content must start with `class`? Remove it, because and html page stast normlay with `<!DOCTYPE`

Comment: This is a example row from a random website :                 <dd class="db-left">Level 27 (Rare)</dd>

Comment: Look `/$abc^/` matches `abc` but not `1abc2`. `/abc/` matches `abc` `1abc3` `1abc` ...

Comment: edited , that $ remained from a different test with the same result in null.

Comment: change `Level[ ]?d+` because of the space. And you this http://www.regexpal.com/ to make you regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using `\d` correctly to indicate a digit. It needs the backslash.
You're also not going to match "Level 27" unless you cater for the whitespace between "Level" and the number:

```
preg_match('/class="db-left">Level\s+(\d+)/', $page, $level_match);
```

This works with:

```
$page = '<dd class="db-left">Level 27 (Rare)</dd>';
preg_match('/class="db-left">Level\s+(\d+)/', $page, $level_match);  
var_dump($level_match);
```

I've added parentheses around the `\d` to the answer because you've changed the question slightly to ask for just the extracted numbers:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(24) "class="db-left">Level 27"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "27"
}
```

Comment: Tested it , still null when using : echo '<pre>'; print_r($level_match); echo '</pre>';

Comment: Then you're typing in a different string to match against than the one you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract your number for you. The `$` was searching for your match at the start of the line, which doesn't work so great with long HTML pages. You also need to add a `\` to the d+ to tell it you want to search for a digit. Then wrap the `\d+` in `(` `)` to separate the match from the rest.

```
preg_match('/class="db-left">Level (\d+)/', $page, $level_match);

var_dump($level_match[1])
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$page` to make sure it's coming through correctly?

Comment: this one worked , just tested it again with a different side , just noticed i was checking a null one :) some will be like this